# Make table cell to take as much space and ellipsis if needed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't quite get it to work the way i want it to. I am using `div` elements with display styles of `table`, `row`, `cell`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have first two cells to be fixed, the third cell should expand until it hits the bound. The fourth cell should be shrunk to the size of a content.

In short these are the cell anchors i'm trying to achieve:

```
cell1 - left, right  
cell2 - left, right  
cell3 - left  
cell4 - right
```

I want cell3 to start ellipsing the text once it reaches the right bound.

**First attempt**

```css
.ul {
  overflow: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.li {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 20px 5px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell1 {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.cell2 {
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 10%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.cell3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #999;
  width: auto;
}

.cell4 {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: -15px -20px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
          A
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
          B
        </div>
        <div class="cell3">
          C long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
        </div>
        <div class="cell4">
          D
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, long text just expands the cell3 (C) bayond the size of a table. The cell4 (D) is thrown out. "A" has shrunk even tho it was set to be 50px wide. B has also shrunk, but seems like it stays at `min-width: 30px`

**Second attempt**
Using a `table-layout: fixed` style.

```css
.ulc {
  overflow: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.lic {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 20px 5px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell1 {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.cell2 {
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 10%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.cell3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #999;
  width: auto;
}

.cell4 {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: -15px -20px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulc">
  <li class="lic">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
          A
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
          B
        </div>
        <div class="cell3">
          C long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
        </div>
        <div class="cell4">
          D
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, A has grown to 50px now. B has also grown to what is 10% of the row. The "C" and "D" seems to of equal width.

**Third attempt**
I have seen solutions where people say that "D" should be set to `width: 1px; white-space: nowrap`.

```css
.ulc {
  overflow: visible;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

.lic {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 20px 5px 10px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell1 {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.cell2 {
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 10%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.cell3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #999;
  width: auto;
}

.cell4 {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: -15px -20px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #888;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulc">
  <li class="lic">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell1">
          A
        </div>
        <div class="cell2">
          B
        </div>
        <div class="cell3">
          C long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
        </div>
        <div class="cell4">
          D
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here you can see than i am somewhat getting close to what i want, but still "D" is thrown out and there is no background color, so this means, the cell IS 1px wide. So again, that is bad. It should not be less than the contents of a cell and it all should fit into the LI element.

I have not yet found a fourth solution yet as i'm lost now and don't know what can i do different.

I also couldn't manage to get it working with `inline-block`, even tho it is not good for me, as content doesnt get vertically aligned to middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use table then use a real `<table>` + `<colgroup>` + `<col>` and set the `width` on the `<col style="width:50px;>` tags, you still need `table-layout: fixed` and `width: 100%`. Be aware `min-width` or `max-width` may not work correctly with table cells.

But such layout can be achieved easier with flexbox, example:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 50px;                    /* or flex: 0 0 50px; */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-2 {
  min-width: 30px;
  width: 10%;                     /* or flex: 0 0 10%; */
  background-color: aqua;
}

.col-3 {
  flex: 1;                        /* take avaiable space */
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background-color: gold;
}

.col-4 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="col-1">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    C long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why did you use `width`, not `flex` property for child elements?

Comment: They both works in the case I just copied what OP has as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using `flexbox`

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
}
 
.cell-1 {
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    text-align: center;
}

.cell-2 {
    flex: 0 0 10%;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
.cell-3 {
    background-color: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: auto;
}

.cell-4 {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell-1">A</div>
  <div class="cell-2">B</div>
  <div class="cell-3">C long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long</div>
  <div class="cell-4">D</div>
</div>
```